# Recovery is rewritten

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, recovery-mode, twrp

I am using a Lenovo p70 which I flashed with AOSP 6.0 ported from Lenovo k3.

The ROM keeps overwriting the TWRP custom recovery with stock recovery (which doesn't even boot).
As far as I know this problem is caused by the fact that /system is mounted as read-only. In most cases twrp must promp you and take care about that but that is not my case.
Also I tried editing "fstab.mt6752" but it gets overwritten on boot/reboot and the default values are returned.

So the question is how do I stop the ROM (AOSP) from overwriting the TWRP?
And in case I am right, how do I make system to be mounted as read-write by default?

Comment: After flashing custom recovery, try rebooting from recovery itself to system rather than rebooting normally ( to bypass inbuilt protection of  restoring with stock)

Comment: In the most time, this what I did. The process of overwriting is done by the recovery.

Comment: Delete `/system/boot-from-recovery.p` if it exists. Are you able to write to `/system` after all? I can't seem to make that out from your post.

Comment: I will try. And yes, I can write system, but I need to do mount -o remount,rw /system.

Comment: @beeshyams I meant that the process of overwriting is done by the kernel. But I can't edit the comment anymore.

Comment: Understood... afraid I can't help you there

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already done. But, most customs like CM, have an option in developer settings to not overwrite recovery.

Comment: AOSP is more or less a stock rather than custom rom. It is almost unmodified and there is no such option.